# Need help with this shell script getting output as zero

Tags: bash, scripts

Seeing `FINAL_TIME = 0`, please help me

```
set START_TIME = 1475614806
set END_TIME = $(date +%s)
set FINAL_TIME = $((END_TIME - START_TIME))
printf "%dh %dm %ds" "$((FINAL_TIME/3600))" "$((FINAL_TIME%3600/60))" "$((FINAL_TIME%60))" > reports/tle_top.duration.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, following script worked START_TIME=1475614806
END_TIME=$(date +%s)
FINAL_TIME=$((END_TIME-START_TIME))
printf "%dh %dm %ds" "$((FINAL_TIME/3600))" "$((FINAL_TIME%3600/60))" "$((FINAL_TIME%60))" > reports/tle_top.duration.txt

Answer (score 6):

In bash,

```
set START_TIME = 1475614806
```

sets `$1` to `START_TIME`, `$2` to `=`, and `$3` to the number. The syntax of assignment is

```
START_TIME=1475614806
```

No `set`, not spaces.

Comment: Nice short explanation of `set`, but you're missing that he attempts to read the variables' values incorrectly.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Dollar signs are not needed in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Oh, you're actually right. Well, learned something. Have my upvote then :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `set` to assign Bash variables. You simply write `variable_name=value`, but note there may be *no space* around the `=` operator!

To read the value of a variable, you must normally (as @choroba correctly pointed out, this is not necessary inside `$(( ... ))` arithmetic expressions) write a `$` in front of its name, like `$variable_name`.

```
START_TIME=1475614806
END_TIME=$(date +%s)
FINAL_TIME=$(($END_TIME - $START_TIME))
printf "%dh %dm %ds" "$(($FINAL_TIME/3600))" "$(($FINAL_TIME%3600/60))" "$(($FINAL_TIME%60))" > reports/tle_top.duration.txt
```